# Free OS (no proprietary software or drivers) with current software?

Tags: distribution-choice, free-software

I heard gnewsense has no proprietary software or drivers so I thought I should give it a try. I was disappointed to see openoffice instead of libreoffice, an old version of nginx, clang, etc and missing things such as add-apt-repository, software-properties-common python-software-properties.

Is there a linux distro that has reasonably modern version of software and doesn't have a ton of commands missing?

Comment: Voting to close: "doesn't have a ton of commands missing" makes this subjective, ie., opinion-based...

Comment: @jasonwryan Really? Number of packages available in comparison with popular distros (such as Ubuntu) is something subjective to you?

Comment: @Dmitry Define "ton". Then define "reasonably modern." Then try and work out where *you* would draw the line, because I guarantee it will differ from what I have in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is the list](http://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html) of GNU/Linux distributions, that are considered completely free by Free Software Foundation. Besides gNewSense, it includes BLAG, Dragora, Dynebolic, Musix, Parabola, Trisquel and Ututo XS. You mentioned, you had been missed `add-apt-repository`, which, afaik, is from Ubuntu, so from that list you probably would be interested in Trisquel, which is basically Ubuntu [cleaned](http://trisquel.info/en/wiki/how-trisquel-made) from proprietary software and blobs.

But actually you can get any popular GNU distro, that keeps free and non-free well-separated from each other – Debian is one of them (install `testing` release at least if you want up-to-date software) – and just do not install anything non-free, do not ever enable repos containing proprietary packages: `non-free` and `contrib` for Debian.

Comment: In the initial edition of my answer I mentioned Ubuntu on a par with Debian as a distro that keeps free and non-free code well-separated. Unfortunately, that seems to be incorrect: while Debian indeed got rid of the binary blobs in Linux® since version 6, Ubuntu still include them [according to Trisquel](http://trisquel.info/en/wiki/how-trisquel-made). Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Debian and, besides not enabling proprietary repositores, use [`vrms`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrms) to verify whether you have proprietary software.

Similar utilities might exist for other distros.

Comment: It is not that simple utility (which is essentially the same as `$ aptitude search '?installed (?section(restricted) | ?section(multiverse))'`), who does the work, but vigilant maintainers of distribution, who classify software. `vrms` is completely useless against some random software from numerous personal repos over the Web.